# Separating data into files based on random ID numbers using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have a tab delimited file(1993_NYA.tab) with radiosonde data containing its' ID. I want to extract data of each ID into separate tab files. The file looks like this.

```
1993-01-01T10:45:03 083022143   250 78.93018    11.95426    960.0   -16.8   76  1.7 276
1993-01-01T10:45:16 083022143   300 78.93011    11.95529    953.7   -17.2   77  1.8 288
1993-01-01T10:45:30 083022143   350 78.93000    11.95638    947.3   -17.6   79  2.0 297
```

Here 083022143 is the ID but it changes randomly(not in ascending order). The code I tried is as follows.

```
ID=$(cat 1993_NYA.tab | cut -f 2 | sort | uniq)
for i in {$ID}
do
awk -F '\t' '$2 = "$i"' 1993_NYA.tab > 1993_$i.tab
done
```

This is not storing data of a particular ID into filename containing the same ID. Can anyone please help.

Comment: How many different unique ids are there?

Comment: Could you please also mention how the output files name look like?

Comment: I had answered this question but looks like more information needed on this one so deleting it till you provide more information on questions. Once info is added will edit and undelete it then.

Comment: There are almost 300 unique IDs. The problem is solved by now. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

There are three small mistakes.

- `{$ID}` should be just `$ID`.
- `'$2 = "$i"'` has the assignment operator `=` rather than the comparison `==`.
- `'$2 = "$i"'` does not interpolate the value of *i* into the argument because of the single quotes; we can write e. g. `"\$2 == $i"` instead.

With the above changes, your code works. But `awk` has built-in magic which makes the task much easier. The single command

```
awk -F '\t' '{print >"1993_"$2".tab"}' 1993_NYA.tab
```

does what you want.